# Html body style "padding-top" not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, offsetheight

Why when i'm doing:

```
document.body.style["padding-top"] =  panel.offsetHeight + "px";
```

the `"padding-top"` is not working in Firefox? It is ok in Chrome & IE , but FF - stab in the back.

The whole code is:

```
var fixTopPanel = function(){
  var panel = document.getElementById("TopPanel");
  document.body.style["padding-top"] =  panel.offsetHeight + "px";
}

window.addEventListener("load", fixTopPanel);
window.addEventListener("resize", fixTopPanel);
```

See it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KyxxRV?p=preview

UPD: just [figured out](http://plnkr.co/edit/SA0jdaz6rSaBRCSkhlG1?p=preview) that `style.paddingTop`  works but what is the problem with `"padding-top"`?

Comment: `document.body.style["paddingTop"]`

Comment: have you tried paddingTop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paddingTop like this : `element.style.paddingTop`.

```
var fixTopPanel = function(){
  var panel = document.getElementById("TopPanel");
  document.body.style.paddingTop =  panel.offsetHeight + "px";
}

window.addEventListener("load", fixTopPanel);
window.addEventListener("resize", fixTopPanel);
```

Comment: Even IE likes "padding-top" , so what is Firefox' problem??

Comment: Firefox don't support this. paddingTop is W3C norme.

Comment: can you please attach relevant links?

Comment: "padding-top" is CSS property, "paddingTop" is JS property. http://help.dottoro.com/ljavoeag.php